# find area of 2 coordinates

Tags: c#, points

How can I find the area of the rectangle formed with 2 2-dimensional Vectors. ex:
p1 = (20, 40);
p2 = (30, 60);

I need to find the rectangle this forms. Is there a common used formula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just multiply the lengths of the sides of the rectangle, which are the differences between the coordinates of the two vectors:

```
(p2.X - p1.X) * (p2.Y - p1.Y)
```